# W, A,S, D movement in Unity, don't know how to use new funtions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Hello i have a problem with animation controller script used to play animations depending on which key is pressed

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
        function UpdateAnimations()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                animation.CrossFade("goup");
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                animation.CrossFade("goleft");
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            {
                animation.CrossFade("goright");
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                animation.CrossFade("godown");
            }

        }

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateAnimations();
    }
```

It says that "Component.animation" is too old, and i should use GetComponent but i don't know how to

Answer (score 1):

First of all you most probably mean `void` instead of `function` as your code is in `c#` not [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) (which is also long deprecated by now)

---

And then **Yes**, how old is that code you got there? The direct accesses to things like [`Component.animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-animation.html), [`Component.renderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-renderer.html), [`Component.camera`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-camera.html) were deprecated years ago ^^

As the error already tells you rather use e.g. [`Component.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) like e.g.

```
public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference this via the Inspector in Unity
    // via drag and drop. Then you don't need GetComponent at all
    [SerializeField] private Animation _animation;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // or as fallback get it on runtime
        if(!_animation) _animation = GetCompoenent<Animation>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateAnimations();
    }

    private void UpdateAnimations()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            _animation.CrossFade("goup");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            _animation.CrossFade("goleft");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            _animation.CrossFade("goright");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            _animation.CrossFade("godown");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined "animation" in your code?

you could try adding animation reference in the top of the code:

```
private Animation animation;
```

and in your Start() or Awake() method, add:

```
// will add reference to the animation to be the Animation component
// in this GameObject
animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
```